# Theme Check errors about missing CSS rules

Tags: css, errors

```
REQUIRED: .wp-caption css class is needed in your theme css.
REQUIRED: .wp-caption-text css class is needed in your theme css.
REQUIRED: .sticky css class is needed in your theme css.
REQUIRED: .screen-reader-text css class is needed in your theme css. See See: the Codex for an example implementation.
REQUIRED: .gallery-caption css class is needed in your theme css.
REQUIRED: .alignright css class is needed in your theme css.
REQUIRED: .alignleft css class is needed in your theme css.
REQUIRED: .aligncenter css class is needed in your theme css.
```

I am getting the above error when I am running the theme-check plugin, but the problem is that I don't have any use of these classes in my theme. what should  I do? Just use them for the sake of only getting rid of errors? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme check plugin checks your theme also for any default class that is generated by WordPress itself. Take a look into [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes) for some more info.

All you have to do, is to cover these classes in your CSS file, for example:

```
.alignleft {
    text-align:left
}
```

This will remove the errors from theme checker plugin.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, but don't you think that this will generate not needed CSS?

Comment: These classes are used by native WordPress functions. For example, if you align an image in your post to the left, WordPress will automatically add an `alignleft` class to the image, without you even knowing about it. So i would suggest you cover them all, you never know what happens later :)

Comment: so i cover them Like you told me for all those classes that generated errors, right sir?

Comment: @TheWPNovice Yes sir that is what you should do. Some markets such as envato won't even let you publish your theme if you don't cover these classes.

Comment: ok. Thanks, but wont these people like at envato think that we are fooling them just to get rid of errors or thats ok?

Comment: @TheWPNovice No it's not really fooling. These classes will be used somewhere, they are automatically added and used, and their name represents what they do. So covering them is necessary and is actually a neat work rather than fooling anyone.

Comment: thanks. please do upvote me if you like this question. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @TheWPNovice You are welcome. I already did.